# Making an Object faster in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I'm making a 2D game in unity and I'm stuck. I have a rigidbody2d projectile that is fired based on the click position. I want to make this projectile faster without changing its trajectory or changing the timescale of the entire world and I cant change the gravity scale. Any ideas ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: get velocity, get velocity length (aka distance), normalize velocity, multiply with length/distance + how much faster you want it to be, assign velocity

Answer (score 0):

give the object less mass, for one. But if you are using a Vector for velocity so.

Where ever you are setting the velocity of the bullet in the script, add this (in JavaScript)

```
var speed = 2.5;  // or what ever you want it to be, play with it

// as long as you multiply both x and y the same, they will keep their direction.
gameObject.rigidbody2D.velocity.x *= speed;
gameObject.rigidbody2D.velocity.y *= speed;
```